# Understanding WCHAR**

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to pass `WCHAR**` type variable to function. I expect this function will get some text to this variable. But what `WCHAR**` is really is? According to my understanding `WCHAR*` is pointer to `WCHAR` array.  `WCHAR**` then is array of `WCHAR*`?

How to initialize this variable?

```
WCHAR** c;

void func (WCHAR** s)
{

}
```

Compiler is angry, that `c` is not initialized. How to deal with that?

This is real function that is generated from wsdl for web service. I need to pass `cConfig` variable.

```
HRESULT WINAPI WSHttpBinding_ISupportService_ConfigToClient(
    __in WS_SERVICE_PROXY* _serviceProxy,
    __in int clientId, 
    __out int* ConfigToClientResult, 
    __inout_opt __deref __nullterminated WCHAR** cConfig, 
    __in WS_HEAP* _heap,
    __in_ecount_opt(_callPropertyCount) const WS_CALL_PROPERTY* _callProperties,
    __in const ULONG _callPropertyCount,
    __in_opt const WS_ASYNC_CONTEXT* _asyncContext,
    __in_opt WS_ERROR* _error)
{
    void* _argList[3]; 
    _argList[0] = &clientId;
    _argList[1] = &ConfigToClientResult;
    _argList[2] = &cConfig;
    return WsCall(_serviceProxy,
        (WS_OPERATION_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.contracts.WSHttpBinding_ISupportService.WSHttpBinding_ISupportService_ConfigToClient.WSHttpBinding_ISupportService_ConfigToClient,
        (const void **)&_argList,
        _heap,
        _callProperties,
        _callPropertyCount,
        _asyncContext,
        _error);
}
const _tempuri_org_wsdl tempuri_org_wsdl =
{
    {// messages
        {    // message description for ISupportService_LogIt_InputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_LogIt_InputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/LogIt
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.LogIt, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_LogIt_InputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_LogIt_OutputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_LogIt_OutputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/LogItResponse
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.LogItResponse, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_LogIt_OutputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_getClientId_InputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_getClientId_InputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/getClientId
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.getClientId, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_getClientId_InputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_getClientId_OutputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_getClientId_OutputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/getClientIdResponse
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.getClientIdResponse, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_getClientId_OutputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_GetClientCommands_InputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_GetClientCommands_InputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/GetClientCommands
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.GetClientCommands, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_GetClientCommands_InputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_GetClientCommands_OutputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_GetClientCommands_OutputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/GetClientCommandsResponse
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.GetClientCommandsResponse, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_GetClientCommands_OutputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToSrv_InputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_ConfigToSrv_InputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/ConfigToSrv
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.ConfigToSrv, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToSrv_InputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToSrv_OutputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_ConfigToSrv_OutputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/ConfigToSrvResponse
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.ConfigToSrvResponse, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToSrv_OutputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToClient_InputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_ConfigToClient_InputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/ConfigToClient
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.ConfigToClient, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToClient_InputMessage
        {    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToClient_OutputMessage
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.ISupportService_ConfigToClient_OutputMessageactionName, // http://tempuri.org/ISupportService/ConfigToClientResponse
            (WS_ELEMENT_DESCRIPTION*)&tempuri_org_xsd.globalElements.ConfigToClientResponse, 
        },    // message description for ISupportService_ConfigToClient_OutputMessage
    }, // messages
    {// contracts
        {   // WSHttpBinding_ISupportService
            5,
            (WS_OPERATION_DESCRIPTION**)tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.contracts.WSHttpBinding_ISupportService.operations,
        },    // end of WSHttpBinding_ISupportService
    }, // contracts
    { // policies
        {  // template description for WSHttpBinding_ISupportService
            {  // channel properties
                (WS_CHANNEL_PROPERTY*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.policies.WSHttpBinding_ISupportService.channelPropertiesArray,
                3,
            },
        },  // end of template description
    },  // policies
    { // endpointReferences
        { // WSHttpBinding_ISupportService
            { // endpointAddressDescription
                WS_ADDRESSING_VERSION_1_0,
            },
            (WS_XML_STRING*)&tempuri_org_wsdlLocalDefinitions.dictionary.xmlStrings.WSHttpBinding_ISupportServiceendpointReferenceString, // <wsa10:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">...
        },  // endof WSHttpBinding_ISupportService
    },  // endof endpointReferences 
}; // end of _tempuri_org_wsdl
```

Comment: It's a pointer to a pointer but not necessarily a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers. If you need an array of `WCHAR` pointers use `std::vector<WCHAR*>` or `std::vector<std::wstring>`

Comment: `WCHAR**` in a function signature would either expect an array of wide character strings (but would also need a size or some indication of the end of the array) or it will be modifying the address of something in a way that would be visible to the caller of the function.

Comment: so, how I can define WCHAR** type variable, inicialize and pass to my function

Comment: @vico what you've shown us tells us nothing of what the function needs. I would *guess* `WCHAR* s; func(&s);` if `func` will be assigning to `s` in a way that you would use it after it returns.

Answer (score 1):

@crashmstr provided the answer in a comment, here is how you would do it in practice, assuming the function wants to return a pointer to you.

```
WCHAR* ptr = NULL;
func(&ptr);
if(ptr) {
    DoSomething(ptr);
    ...
    MaybeYouHaveToFreeThePointer(ptr);
}
```